# Show that $S$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> Let $S=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:||x||=1\}$ with $ n>1$. Show $S$ is connected without using arcwise connectedness.

I would be done if I can show this: Let $X$ be a connected space and $A\subset X$ be closed in $X$. Then $A$ is connected.

However I am not sure that this is even true. If it were true then I can note that $S$ is closed and subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (which is connected) so $S$ is connected.

Even if I were to use arc-connectedness, for some unknown reason I am facing difficulty in writing the function that generates the arc. In fact $S$ is actually the surface of an $n$-dimensional sphere. If I take $x_1,x_2\in S$ then I can find the angle $\theta$ between them. Then taking any one of $x_1,x_2$ as a starting vector maybe I can describe all points on the arc joining $x_1$ and $x_2$. But as I said, maybe I am getting confused.

Intuitively I can use Arc Connectedness because obviously all points in $S$ are on some arc!! But I can't really prove it analytically.

Comment: It clearly isn’t true: if $A$ is a two-point set in $\Bbb R^n$, $A$ is closed but not connected. Note that the theorem requires $n\ge 2$: if $n=1$, $S=\{-1,1\}$, which is not connected.

Comment: Are you allowed to assume $\mathbb R^n$\ $0$ is connected. If not, prove it and if so, define a continuous function from that space onto the sphere. Since continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets the result follows.

Comment: Yes I am @JohnDouma. I was actually thinking how I can construct this continuous function. I believe this works: Take$ X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in \mathbb R^n-\{0\}$. Consider $r=||X||>0$. Then let $Y=(x_1/r,...,x_n/r)$. Note $Y\in S$. Consider the map $X\mapsto Y$. This is continuous and this map works!!

Comment: @AlecTeal This is not the question, and indeed the proof I know uses continuous functions and $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$. Did you have an elementary proof in mind?

Comment: Further to Brian M. Scott's insightful comment, $S$ itself is not connected if $n = 1$.  Please edit the question to fix these problems and to ask something a bit more specific.

Comment: Okay, but this was the question as exactly printed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple proof by contradiction :For $2 \le n$ the space $S^{n-1}= \{x \in R^n : ||x||=1 \}$ is a closed subspace of the compact Hausdorff space $[-1,1]^n$ so $S^{n-1}$ is compact.  Now suppose $S^{n-1}=A \cup B$ where $A,B$ are disjoint non-empty open-and-closed subsets.WLOG, $p=(x_j : j=1..n) \in A $, where $p_1=1$ and $p_j=0$ for $j>1$. Now B is closed and non-empty, and $S^{n-1}$ is a compact metric space, so there exists $q \in  B$ with ||p-q||= $\min \{ ||p-r|| : r \in  B \}$. EXERCISE: If $q\in S^{n-1}$ and $q \ne p$, any neighborhood of $q$ contains a point $s$ with $||p-s||<||p-q||$. But some neighborhood of $q$ is a subset of $B$,and will therefore contain a point $s \in B$ such that $||p-s||<||p-q||$, contradicting the definition of $q$.(Note that the exercise is where we require $n>1$.)